# Print the line matching 'pattern' string, excluding the 'pattern'

Tags: regex, linux

I have the following lines in a text file 'file.txt'

```
String1 ABCDEFGHIJKL
String2 DCEGIJKLQMAB
```

I want to print the characters corresponding to 'String1' in another text file 'text.txt' like this

```
ABCDEFGHIJKL
```

Here, I don't want to use any line numbers. Any suggestions using 'sed' command?. I tried with between 'string 1' and 'string 2', but couldn't obtain command excluding 'string1'. This following code for excluding only 'string2'.

```
sed -n '/^string1/,/^string2/{p;/^string2/q}' file.txt | sed '$d' > text.txt
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use GNU `grep`:

```
grep -Po 'String1\s+\K.*' in_file
```

Here, `grep` uses the following options:
`-P` : Use Perl regexes.
`-o` : Print the matches only (1 match per line), not the entire lines.

`\K` : Cause the regex engine to "keep" everything it had matched prior to the `\K` and not include it in the match. Specifically, ignore the preceding part of the regex when printing the match.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`grep` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html)
[perlre - Perl regular expressions](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre)

Comment: Using perl is overkill and requires a large number of packages to be installed on linux that are mostly obsolete now.

Comment: @EamonnKenny The answer is using [GNU `grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html), as I mentioned, **not** Perl. GNU `grep` comes pre-installed on Linux, and requires no packages to be installed. In particular, Perl does not need to be installed. GNU `grep` has option `-P`, allowing one to use Perl regular expressions, which are quite powerful.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '$1=="String1" { print $2 }' file.txt > text.txt
```

Where the first space delimited field equals "String1", print the second field. Redirect the output to text.txt.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Suppose if i need to print the entire line instead of only the second field, how can i modify this code?

Comment: just use { print } as opposed to { print $2 }

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!. In this sense while using { print } for the line, it printed "string1 ABCDEFGHIJKL". Just one last clarification, suppose if i have a line- "string1 ABC DEF GHI JKL" and i want to print the line using the above command to get only "ABC DEF GHI JKL" excluding string1. How can i modify?

Comment: awk '$1=="String1" { gsub("string1 ","",$0);print $0 }' file.txt > text.txt

Comment: If the solution meets your needs, please take the time to up vote and accept the answer.